# .json file to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an array of json objects in .json file which i need to represent as a HTML table.
Can anyone please help me with how to go about it.
The test.json file has data like:

```
[{"Date":"2013/02/26"},{"Scn1":{"Avg":500 , "Count":5 , "Max":700}},{"Scn2":{"Avg":800 , "Count":6 , "Max":1000}},{"Scn3":{"Avg":500 , "Count":5 , "Max":700}}]
```

I need to represent it as a HTML table like:

```
Date:_______

|Scenario | Avg value | Count | Max value |
|         |           |       |           |
|         |           |       |           |
|         |           |       |           |
```

Comment: if you know nothing: http://danml.com/bind/

Comment: have a look at handlebars or mustache or jquery templates.

Comment: How about reading the .json file from a java file and then creating a table from the java file itself?
Does it seem a good option?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question and the comments (and down-votes) are right, you should provide more information about what you've tried before posting. But I'm in a happy mood, so...

That data is in a pretty bad format for looping through. If you have the ability to tweak it a little, do so. Anything that is one-to-many should be an array (one date has many scenarios). Anything that is one-to-one should be properties of the same object (e.g. scenario name and average). Once you data is in the 'right' format you'll need a nested loop for each level of the hierarchy. You have two levels (dates and scenarios) so you'll have two loops. Each will write a row.

Then the general idea would be:

```
var dataSet = [{"Date":"2013/02/26",
                scenarios: [
                  {name: "Scn1","Avg": 500,"Count": 5,"Max": 700},
                  {name: "Scn2","Avg": 800,"Count": 6,"Max": 1000},
                  {name: "Scn3","Avg":500,"Count":5,"Max":700}
                ]
              }];


(function draw(data) {
  var i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $('#myTable').append('<tr><td colspan="4">' + data[i].Date + '</td></tr>');
      $('#myTable').append('<tr>');
      $('#myTable').append('<td>Scenario</td>');
      $('#myTable').append('<td>Average</td>');
      $('#myTable').append('<td>Count</td>');
      $('#myTable').append('<td>Max</td>');
      $('#myTable').append('</tr>');

      for (var j = 0; j < data[i].scenarios.length; j++) {
          $('#myTable').append('<tr>');
          $('#myTable').append('<td>' + data[i].scenarios[j].name + '</td>');
          $('#myTable').append('<td>' + data[i].scenarios[j].Avg + '</td>');
          $('#myTable').append('<td>' + data[i].scenarios[j].Count + '</td>');
          $('#myTable').append('<td>' + data[i].scenarios[j].Max + '</td>');
          $('#myTable').append('</tr>');
      }
    }
})(dataSet);
```

This is using jQuery to add elements to the DOM. There will be libraries and plugins to do this. If you want a quick fix, you may look at them. If you're beginning with JavaScript and want to be an expert one day, best to get your head around looping and traversing objects first.

Note that to do all of this you have to make the test.json file available to your code. You would probably do this with AJAX, I'd suggest reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ub587/2/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) You're assuming the OP (or other readers) can look at your code and intuit that you're using jQuery (or similar 3rd party lib). 2) You do not show readers of your answer how to parse JSON into the JS object which your code iterates.